# RcppArmadillo: diagonal matrix multiplication is very slow

Tags: rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

Let `x` be a vector and `M` a matrix.

In R, I can do

```
D <- diag(exp(x))
crossprod(M, D%M)
```

and in RcppArmadillo, I have the following which is much slower.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat multiple_mnv(const arma::vec& x, const arma::mat& M) {
  arma::colvec diagonal(x.size())
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
  {
    diagonal(i) = exp(x[i]);
  }
  arma::mat D = diagmat(diagonal);
  return     M.t()*D*M;
}
```

Why is this so slow? How can I speed this up?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? How did you benchmark it?

Comment: Try changing `return M.t()*D*M` to `return M.t()*diagmat(diagonal)*M`. The latter expression gives Armadillo more information on what `diagonal` is, so it may optimize more. Note that the generation of `diagonal` is redundant, as this expression should also work: `return M.t()*diagmat(arma::exp(x))*M`

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow [manju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12314043/manju). For future questions, please be advised that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is expected, and in fact is in your best interest to provide; it helps others help you. Here's an example of how you could provide example data for others to work with:

```r
## Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
## Generate data
x <- rnorm(10)
M <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
## Output code for others to copy your objects
dput(x)
dput(M)
```

This is the data I will work with to show that your C++ code is in fact **not slower** than R. I used your C++ code (adding in a missing semicolon):

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat foo(const arma::vec& x, const arma::mat& M) {
    arma::colvec diagonal(x.size());
    for ( int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++ )
    {
        diagonal(i) = exp(x[i]);
    }
    arma::mat D = diagmat(diagonal);
    return M.t() * D * M;
}
```

Note also that I had to make some of my own choices about the type of the return object and types of the function arguments (this is one of the places where a minimal reproducible example could help you: What if these choices affect my results?) I then create an R function to do what `foo()` does:

```r
bar <- function(v, M) {
    D <- diag(exp(v))
    return(crossprod(M, D %*% M))
}
```

Note also that I had to fix a typo you had, changing `D%M` to `D %*% M`. Let's double check they give the same results:

```r
all.equal(foo(x, M), bar(x, M))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now let's explore how fast they are:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(cpp = foo(x, M), R = foo(x, M), times = 1e5)
bench
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min     lq     mean median     uq      max
#   cpp 22.185 23.015 27.00436 23.204 23.461 31143.30
#     R 22.126 23.028 25.48256 23.216 23.475 29628.86
```

Those look pretty much the same to me! We can also look at a density plot of the times (throwing out the extreme value outliers to make things a little clearer):

```r
cpp_times <- with(bench, time[expr == "cpp"])
R_times   <- with(bench, time[expr == "R"])
cpp_time_dens <- density(cpp_times[cpp_times < quantile(cpp_times, 0.95)])
R_time_dens   <- density(R_times[R_times < quantile(R_times, 0.95)])
plot(cpp_time_dens, col = "blue", xlab = "Time (in nanoseconds)", ylab = "",
     main = "Comparing C++ and R execution time")
lines(R_time_dens, col = "red")
legend("topright", col = c("blue", "red"), bty = "n", lty = 1,
       legend = c("C++ function (foo)", "R function (bar)"))
```

[image]

### Why?

As helpfully pointed out by [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) in the comments, in the end both R and Armadillo are going to be calling a LAPACK or BLAS routine anyways -- you shouldn't expect much difference unless you can give Armadillo a hint on how to be more efficient.

### Can we make the Armadillo code faster?

Yes! As pointed out by [mtall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080929/mtall) in the comments, we can give Armadillo the hint that we're dealing with a diagonal matrix. Let's try; we'll use the following code:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat baz(const arma::vec& x, const arma::mat& M) {
    return M.t() * diagmat(arma::exp(x)) * M;
}
```

And benchmark it:

```r
all.equal(foo(x, M), baz(x, M))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(cpp = foo(x, M), R = foo(x, M),
                        cpp2 = baz(x, M), times = 1e5)
bench
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min     lq     mean median     uq      max
#   cpp 22.822 23.757 27.57015 24.118 24.632 26600.48
#     R 22.855 23.771 26.44725 24.124 24.638 30619.09
#  cpp2 20.035 21.218 25.49863 21.587 22.123 36745.72
```

We see a small but sure improvement; let's take a look graphically as we did before:

```r
cpp_times  <- with(bench, time[expr == "cpp"])
cpp2_times <- with(bench, time[expr == "cpp2"])
R_times    <- with(bench, time[expr == "R"])
cpp_time_dens  <- density(cpp_times[cpp_times < quantile(cpp_times, 0.95)])
cpp2_time_dens <- density(cpp2_times[cpp2_times < quantile(cpp2_times, 0.95)])
R_time_dens    <- density(R_times[R_times < quantile(R_times, 0.95)])
xlims <- range(c(cpp_time_dens$x, cpp2_time_dens$x, R_time_dens$x))
ylims <- range(c(cpp_time_dens$y, cpp2_time_dens$y, R_time_dens$y))
ylims <- ylims * c(1, 1.15)
cols  <- c("#0072b2", "#f0e442", "#d55e00")
cols  <- c("#e69f00", "#56b4e9", "#009e73")
labs  <- c("C++ original", "C++ improved", "R")
plot(cpp_time_dens, col = cols[1], xlim = xlims, ylim = ylims,
     xlab = "Time (in nanoseconds)", ylab = "",
     main = "Comparing C++ and R execution time")
lines(cpp2_time_dens, col = cols[2])
lines(R_time_dens, col = cols[3])
legend("topleft", col = cols, bty = "n", lty = 1, legend = labs, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and patient answer. The "tl;dr" is, of course, that it all ends up in the same LAPACK/BLAS subroutine so we expect performance to be similar (module overhead in "how the data gets there").

Comment: Try changing `return M.t()*D*M` to `return M.t()*diagmat(diagonal)*M`. The latter expression gives Armadillo more information on what `diagonal` is, so it may optimize more. Note that the generation of `diagonal` is redundant, as this expression should also work: `return M.t()*diagmat(arma::exp(x))*M`

Comment: @mtall True. I will add benchmarks with efficient Armadillo code as well, but my main point here was to demonstrate that **given OP's code**, it actually wasn't slower

Comment: @mtall I added something on your mentioned improvement to the code; thanks!